# How to keep a session alive in selenium with phantomjs through nodejs with webdriver.io?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, webdriver-io

I'm using selenium + phantomjs in a node.js environment through webdriver.io.
For some reason the session ends after a while. Selenium is still up, but in its resource hub, there's no more active session.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: How do you start selenium? What do the selenium logs say? Does the session end with another browser, say chome?

Comment: Selenium is spawned within nodejs. Where can i find that log?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Hub times out any inactive sessions by default in order to free up resources for other requests. You can disable this by setting `timeout=0` when starting Hub, either as a command line parameter or through the JSON config depending on how you're starting it.

Keep in mind that if a client crashes with timeouts disabled, that instance will continue to be in-use and won't be available for new sessions.

Sourc: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2#Optional_parameters

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to extend the global timeout to infinity,
you need to execute command before session timeout.

```
const driverTimeout = 60*1000;

// this interval should run before session expired and keep it alive.
const handleNumber = setInterval(() -> driver.getOrientation(), driverTimeout - 1000);

/** do some long async logic **/

// then stop the interval
clearInterval(handleNumber);
```

see more about this
https://l18.me/how-to-keep-alive-appium-driver-da9227b2fa